# How to convert list of word counts into dataframe for sentiment analysis

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a python list objects that looks like this:

```
{'word1':#, 'word2':#, 'word3':#, 'class':'pos'}

{'word2':#, 'word4':#, 'word5':#, 'word6':#, 'class':'neg'}
```

Where each row has a list of words and their word counts from lines in a file, and the last list item is always either pos (positive) or neg (negative). (This is for sentiment analysis).

I'm trying to convert this to a dataframe, where each column is ALL the posible words from each row in the list. And each row has the word count for that item:

df:

```
row   word1   word2   word3   word4   word5   word6   class
1     #       #       #       0       0       0       pos
2     0       #       0       #       #       #       neg
```

How do I go about that? I've tried directly converting it to a dataframe using

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list)
```

but I dont see the class column in my data and I get multiple columns for the same word.

Comment: it seems to python dictionary not a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are dictionaries, not list objects.

You need to make a list with dictionaries:

```
import pandas as pd

list = [{'word1':10, 'word2':34, 'word3':75, 'class':'pos'},
        {'word2':35, 'word4':53, 'word5':3, 'word6':59, 'class':'neg'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=list, index=range(1, len(list)+1))
print(df)

print() # Empty line

df = df.replace(pd.np.nan, "0") # Replace NaN values with 0s
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  class  word1  word2  word3  word4  word5  word6
1   pos   10.0     34   75.0    NaN    NaN    NaN
2   neg    NaN     35    NaN   53.0    3.0   59.0

  class word1  word2 word3 word4 word5 word6
1   pos    10     34    75     0     0     0
2   neg     0     35     0    53     3    59
```